# validation in php to select listbox value before submit form

Tags: php

my table has 3 td on 1 row.

- 1st td has start button.
- 2nd td have listbox.
- 3rd td have stop button.

I only need validation.
when I press **start button** it save all the data of post.
when I press  **stop button,** it should **validate user to select data first from listbox.**

below is my code.on click of both start button and stop button i call below save  code.

```
<?php
        require_once('includes/config.php');        
        $editionmaster = new editionmaster;
        $machine = new machine;     
        if(isset($_POST['save'])) 
        {
            if(isset($_GET['Message']))
            {
            $_POST['Message'] = $_GET['Message'];           
            }
        $_POST['stoptime'] = $date->format('H:i');  
        $_POST['starttime'] = $date->format('H:i');         
        $machine->save($machine->table,$_POST);         
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Data Saved Successfully";
        header('Location: machine_final.php');  
        exit;
        } 
        ?>
```

below is my listbox code

```
<td>
            <select class="form-control" name="Message" style="width:47px; height:20px; background-color:#f4f4f4;">
                 <option value=""></option>
                 <?php 
            foreach($result as $reason)
            {           
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $reason['Alias']; ?>"><?php echo $reason['Message']; ?></option>          
              <?php } ?>            
             </select>
             </td>
```